# A problem of AM>GM

Tags: inequality

> If $n$ is a positive integer with $n> 1$, prove that
>   $$2^{n(n+1)}>(n+1)^{(n+1)}\cdot\left(\frac{n}{1}\right)^n\cdot\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)^{(n-1)}\cdots\left(\frac{2}{n-1}\right)^2\cdot\frac{1}{n}$$

For solving it I have considered the numbers $\displaystyle{n+1,\,n,\,\frac{n-1}{2},\,\ldots,\frac{2}{n-1},\,\frac{1}{n}}$ with associated weights $n+1,n,n-1,\ldots,2,1$ and applied AM>GM
 $$\left[{(n+1)^2+n^2+\frac{(n+1)^2}{2}+\ldots+\frac{2^2}{(n-1)}+\frac{1}{n}}\over{\frac{(n+1)\cdot(n+2)}{2}}\right]^{\tfrac{(n+1)\cdot(n+2)}{2}}$$

but cannot solve it please help

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. For some basic information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: OP: Why did you delete the part of the question showing the computations you tried to solve it?

Comment: this is a problem from the inequality chapter and has come in CU 2011

Comment: @Did : I cannot write it properly

Comment: Oftopic, since somebody had done it for you. Again: why the deletion?

Comment: @Did :yes somebody had done but it was not correct.

Comment: How so? The formula they LaTeXed and the one you had typed are identical.

Comment: the power of the expression was written for the denominator which I wrote was for the whole of it

Comment: As I said, the formula they LaTeXed and the one you had typed are identical.

Comment: I proposed the exact same edit, yet it was rejected... Anyway, instead of removing, why didn't you just post an image of the equation if you didn't know how to LaTeX

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$\left(\frac{n}{1}\right)^n\cdot\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)^{(n-1)}\cdots\left(\frac{2}{n-1}\right)^2\cdot\frac{1}{n} = \binom{n}{0} \binom{n}{1} \cdots \binom{n}{n}$$
where $\binom{n}{k}$ is the usual binomial coefficient.